# Enterprise Library Review?

Tags: logging, exception, enterprise-library

Is enterprise library for exception handling and logging efficient in terms of its memory usage for the functionality provided?

What are the pros and cons?
Thanks

Comment: What technology are we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that the enterprise library is going to be your performance bottleneck. I'd say use it, measure your application's performance, find the bottleneck and go from there. Fretting about what performance *might* be isn't going to give you any useful data for your scenario.

That said, I've had good luck with the Enterprise Library Application Logging Block and I'd recommend it in most cases. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've used EntLib before (in the time of CAB, Object Builder, SmartClient etc).

I believe it to be way too heavy and unflexible.

Better use log4net for logging and custom exception policies for the exception handling (you can easily implement the last thing yourself with EntLib, [like this](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/1/net-exception-handling-action-policies-application-block.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Given the larger memory and faster processing of today's (and recent) computers, I did not have inefficiency problems.  The efficiency I found in the enterprise library is that I did not have to write and test it myself.  And, because of its consistency and documentation, I don't have to spend much time teaching it to anyone else either.  Granted, I have not specifically tested it for speed, and you could likely write a much more targeted custom version without as much overhead...  But again, the efficiency is in using the library itself and moving on to solve other, more important problems.